# Group mysql results by cumulative column value

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a database table `events` and a table `bets`. All bets placed for a particular event are located in the `bets` table while information about the event is stored in the `events` table.

Let's say I have these tables:

```
events table:
id    event_title
1     Call of Duty Finals
2     DOTA 2 Semi-Finals
3     GTA V Air Race


bets table:
id    event_id    amount
1     1           $10
1     2           $50
1     2           $100
1     3           $25
1     3           $25
1     3           $25
```

I want to be able to sort by `popularity` aka how many bets have been placed for that event and by `prize` aka the total amount of money for that event.

**SORTING BY PRIZE**

Obviously this query doesn't work but I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bets GROUP BY event_id SORT BY amount
```

`amount` from the query above should be a cumulative value of all the bet amounts for that `event_id` added together, so this query would return

```
Array (
    [0]=>Array(
            'event_id'=>2
            'amount'=>$150
        )

    [1]=>Array(
            'event_id'=>3
            'amount'=>$75
        )
    [2]=>Array(
            'event_id'=>1
            'amount'=>$10
        )
)
```

**SORTING BY POPULARITY**

Obviously this query doesn't work either but I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bets GROUP BY event_id SORT BY total_rows
```

`total_rows` from the query above should be the number of rows that exist in the `bets` table added together, so this query would return

```
Array (
    [0]=>Array(
            'event_id'=>3
            'total_rows'=>3
        )

    [1]=>Array(
            'event_id'=>2
            'total_rows'=>2
        )
    [2]=>Array(
            'event_id'=>1
            'total_rows'=>1
        )
)
```

I wouldn't necessarily need it to return the `total_rows` value as I could calculate that, but it does need to be sorted by the number of occurrences for that particular `event_id` in the `bets` table.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think count and sum are your friends here:

```
SELECT COUNT(event_id) AS NumberBets, 
    SUM(amount) AS TotalPrize
FROM bets
GROUP BY event_id
```

Should do the trick.
Then you can ORDER BY either the NumberBets(popularity) or TotalPrize as you need. JOIN only needed if you want event titles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM` and `COUNT` aggregate functions:

```
SELECT
    e.id AS event_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
FROM [events] e
LEFT JOIN bets b
    ON b.event_id = e.id
GROUP BY
    e.id
ORDER BY
    sum_amount DESC

SELECT
    e.id AS event_id, COUNT(e.event_id) AS no_of_events
FROM [events] e
LEFT JOIN bets b
    ON b.event_id = e.id
GROUP BY
    e.id
ORDER BY
    no_of_events DESC
```